# Hibernate having difficulty with '@' character in HQL

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql, spring-social

Working with hibernate and spring social,

I am trying to query the database by email address.
when i do this query:

> public Account findAccountByUsername(String username) {
>
> ```
>     Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
>     String selectQuery = "FROM Account as account WHERE account.username = "+username;
>     Query query = session.createQuery(selectQuery);
>     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
>     List<Account> results = query.list();
>
>   if (!results.iterator().hasNext())
>         return null;        
>     return results.iterator().next();       }
> ```

i get this exception

> 2013-01-22 14:37:13,090 [DEBUG] [HibernateTransactionManager,doBegin(),569] - Exposing Hibernate transaction as JDBC transaction [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@3b249bb2]
>   2013-01-22 14:37:13,352 [DEBUG] [QueryTranslatorImpl,parse(),272] - parse() - HQL: FROM masterPackage.model.orm.Account as account WHERE account.username = myEmail@gmail.com
>   2013-01-22 14:37:13,383 [DEBUG] [AbstractPlatformTransactionManager,processRollback(),843] - Initiating transaction rollback
>   2013-01-22 14:37:13,384 [DEBUG] [HibernateTransactionManager,doRollback(),672] - Rolling back Hibernate transaction on Session [org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@294a7134]
>   2013-01-22 14:37:13,385 [DEBUG] [JDBCTransaction,rollback(),186] - rollback
>
> .......
>
> 2013-01-22 14:37:18,818 [WARN] [ProviderSignInController,oauth2Callback(),177] - Exception while handling OAuth2 callback (unexpected char: '@' [FROM masterpackage.model.orm.Account as account WHERE account.username = myEmail@gmail.com]). Redirecting to /signin

is there a way to work around this problem?

There is always a way to save the @ character in the email address as some other character, but i am asking if there is something better then this solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not concatenate HQL query. Use [named parameters](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-parameter-binding-examples/) instead. It is an implementation of [Query Object Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/queryObject.html) in Hibernate.

For your case:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
String selectQuery = "FROM Account as account WHERE account.username = :usernameParam";
Query query = session.createQuery(selectQuery);
query.setParameter("usernameParam", username);
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Account> results = query.list();

if(results.isEmpty()){
    return null;
} else {
    return result;
}
```

---

*Offtop:* recommended never return *null* value for such method. Better is to return an empty collection. For example return new ArrayList<>(); Thus you able to use [Null Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) implicitly.

Comment: Thanks. This works. i am kind of new to Hibernate. had no idea you couldn't do such a thing.