# HQL - Querying by email or string with dot('.') is always returning empty set

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sql-server-2008

This is my HQL Query

```
Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery(
            "from User where username = :usersName ");
    query.setParameter("usersName", usersName);
```

Now if the user name contains dot'.' character its returning empty set other wise its returning the user details.

What I have tried?

> [Hibernate having difficulty with '@' character in HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458986/hibernate-having-difficulty-with-character-in-hql)
>
> Executed the sql query in the server its returning the user details.
>
> Concatenated the parameters directly in query string getting same error.
>
> Tried Criteria Query Got the same problem

where might be the problem?

Comment: The problem might be a leading or trailing space or something similar. If you do a "from User where username LIKE :usersName"  and set `usersName` to the same thing but replacing `@` by `%` what do you get?

Comment: Try the "like", if it works, then the issue is the `@`

Comment: If by same result you mean with the like you get no results, then the issue is not the `@`

Comment: Yes exactly its the problem of dot `.` not the `@` character. I directly tested by changing the values in database

Comment: Maybe your dot (in DB) is some kind of unicode dot, not an ascii one.

Comment: yeah might be, but the encoding of mssql is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS so basically it means ascii http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039211/what-does-collate-sql-latin1-general-cp1-ci-as-do  , Might be hibernate is using some other encoding will verify it once

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this: `query.setString("usersName", usersName);`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
query.setString("usersName", usersName.replaceAll("@", "/@"));
```